# Selenium - iframe within iframe

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find iframe within iframe using Selenium WebDriver. I have a scenario where a popup opens in a website which itself is an iframe and this in turn contains 4 richedit textboxes which are nothing but iframes. Here is how i am trying to do it. If i check the foreach loop, i get 4 iframes correctly which suggests that i am reaching right elements. What can be the reason for failure for not able to get correct tags inside iframe? Here is my code.

```
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> topItem = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='Edit.aspx']"));

        Utility.Instance.WaitUntilFrameLoaded(topItem[0]);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = Utility.Instance.WaitUnitElementsAppearsByXPath("//div[@id='ctlPanel']//table/tbody/tr[2]//iframe[@src='javascript:true;']");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        foreach(IWebElement eleFrame in elements)
        {
            Utility.Instance.WaitUntilFrameLoaded(eleFrame);
            IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
            body.Click();
            driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            Utility.Instance.WaitUntilFrameLoaded(topItem[0]);
         }
```

However i always get the message that the element with tag name body not found. If i debug, i see html which contains a body tag. I am not sure why it does not provide me back with the element.

Comment: if possible can you provide HTML code of that popup

Comment: May not be possible due to security constraints

Comment: Do you get something with `driver.PageSource` ?

Comment: Yeah and it contains body tag

Comment: And with `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body"));` or `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("body")));` ?

Comment: Here is my PageSource <html><head></head><body style="font: 10pt/normal Arial, Verdana; margin: 4px; cursor: text; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;"></body></html> and i get NoSuchElementException

Comment: @RajanPhatak Inside the foreach loop, could you print the  `topItem[0].GetAttribute("outerHTML");` at the first line in the loop?

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer and all i can do webshare to show you the problem if you guys can help